# How to update the ListView in pivot page after updation of data through xaml UI? [Windows Phone 8.1]

Tags: c#, json, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm using a Data Model and Observable Collection to display items in list view. The data stored in a JSON file are displayed in list view. When I add new item to the JSON file I'm successfully able to write that into the file and save. But the change is not reflecting in the Page that shows the list view.

I'm using Navigation_LoadState to load data at the time of application launch. I know INotifyPropertyChanged can do the trick. But don't know how to and where to implement that in order to update the list view. Thanks in advance for your reply.

This is my JSON file that is used to bind the `ListView` at `LoadState`. `Note that the "Members" only have 3 items`

```
"Groups": [
    {
        "UniqueId": "Footballer",
        "Region": "Europe",
        "Country": "England",
        "Members": [
            {
                "UniqueId": "MANU",
                "Name": "Rooney",
                "JerseyNumber": "10",
                "Position": "Forward"
            },
            {
                "UniqueId": "CITY",
                "Name": "Aguero",
                "JerseyNumber": "16",
                "Position": "Forward"
            },
            {
                "UniqueId": "MANU",
                "Name": "Nani",
                "JerseyNumber": "7",
                "Position": "Midfielder"
            }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is the JSON file after adding new item to the `"Members"` runtime via UI. `Now the "Members" have 4 items`.

```
{
"Groups": [
    {
        "UniqueId": "Footballer",
        "Region": "Europe",
        "Country": "England",
        "Members": [
            {
                "UniqueId": "MANU",
                "Name": "Rooney",
                "JerseyNumber": "10",
                "Position": "Forward"
            },
            {
                "UniqueId": "CITY",
                "Name": "Aguero",
                "JerseyNumber": "16",
                "Position": "Forward"
            },
            {
                "UniqueId": "MANU",
                "Name": "Nani",
                "JerseyNumber": "7",
                "Position": "Midfielder"
            },
            {
                "UniqueId": "CITY",
                "Name": "Yaya",
                "JerseyNumber": "5",
                "Position": "Midfielder"
            }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I update this in my `ListView`. I'm using the item names `Rooney`, `Aguero`, `Nani` to bind with ListView.

Comment: Are you binding the json object directly to the ListView ?

Comment: I'm binding the Names of items to the `ListView` in `LoadState`.

Comment: You are doing it in wrong way i guess. Get basic idea about MVVM  .  Create a  TeamMember class and create an observableCollection of it  by parsing JsonObject . Use this observablecollection to bind to the list view Instead of using Json object directly

Comment: See this link about MVVM https://mvvmbasics.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/

Comment: I'm using Data Model. In fact I've Observable collection for `"Members"` How can I implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to a class?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the way you changing the items. If you replace the whole collection with a new one, implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. But if you change the collection items (by adding\removing\replacing items), use `ObservableCollection`, XAML frameworks can automatically handle this.

Comment: I've two `ObsevableCollection`. One is a `DataGroup` and another is a `DataItem`. The later is a property with in the first on. The later one have values like `Name`, `Number`. With the help of XAML UI I'm adding new `DataItem` to the JSON file and replacing it with the old file. But when I go back to the ListView page the addition of new item is not showing. The ListView only contains the Name of the item. But when I close the app and launch again, it updates the ListView. Its is not updating when I go back to the ListView page from the add new item page.

Comment: Did you changed the `DataGroup` collection (by calling `Add()`) or just replaced it with a new collection that contains the same items as the previous one + the new item?

Comment: I actually added new item to the `DataItem` collection runtime and saved in JSON file. I can give you the JSON file at the time of app launch and after adding new item.

Comment: Updated my question. Included JSON file at the time of app launch and after adding new item. please note.